# How to convert image which mode is "1" between PIL and numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm new to image processing with Python and met a strange problem.

For example I have a 2*2 black-white bitmap image which pixels are following:

> black white
>
> white black

Use PIL and convert it to numpy:

```
>>> import Image
>>> import numpy
>>> im = Image.open('test.bmp')
>>> im
<BmpImagePlugin.BmpImageFile image mode=1 size=2x2 at 0x95A54EC>
>>> numpy.asarray(im)
array([[ True,  True],
       [False, False]], dtype=bool)
>>>
```

What puzzles me is the order of pixel in the array. Why not `[[True, False], [False, True]]`? Thanks.

---

UPDATE: the bitmap is here:
http://njuer.us/clippit/test.bmp

Comment: can you post the bitmap?

Comment: http://njuer.us/clippit/test.bmp, made by GIMP

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like there are some bugs with converting to/from numpy with the `1` mode.

If you convert it to `L` first, it works fine:

```
>>> im
<BmpImagePlugin.BmpImageFile image mode=1 size=2x2 at 0x17F17E8>
>>> im2 = im.convert('L')
>>> numpy.asarray(im2)
array([[  0, 255],
       [255,   0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Also, if you try and convert a `bool` numpy array to PIL, you get strange results:

```
>>> testarr = numpy.array([[True,False],[True,False]], dtype=numpy.bool)
>>> testpil = Image.fromarray(testarr, mode='1')
>>> numpy.asarray(testpil)
array([[False, False],
       [False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

However, the exact same thing with `uint8` works fine:

```
>>> testarr = numpy.array([[255,0],[0,255]], dtype=numpy.uint8)
>>> Image.fromarray(testarr)
<Image.Image image mode=L size=2x2 at 0x1B51320>
>>> numpy.asarray(Image.fromarray(testarr))
array([[255,   0],
       [  0, 255]], dtype=uint8)
```

So I would suggest using `L` as an intermediate datatype and then converting to `1` before saving if you need to save it in that format. Something like this:

```
>>> im
<BmpImagePlugin.BmpImageFile image mode=1 size=2x2 at 0x17F17E8>
>>> im2 = im.convert('L')
>>> arr = numpy.asarray(im2)
>>> arr
array([[  0, 255],
       [255,   0]], dtype=uint8)
>>> arr = arr == 255
>>> arr
array([[False,  True],
       [ True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Then to convert back:

```
>>> backarr = numpy.zeros(arr.shape, dtype=numpy.uint8)
>>> backarr[arr] = 255
>>> backarr
array([[  0, 255],
       [255,   0]], dtype=uint8)
>>> Image.fromarray(backarr).convert('1')
<Image.Image image mode=1 size=2x2 at 0x1B41CB0>
```

Comment: `Image.fromarray` has an argument `mode`. `Image.fromarray(testarr, mode='1')` works without exception. But I don't know whether PIL handled it correctly. Is it realy a bug?

Comment: @Clippit thanks for pointing that out. still looks broken though - updated my answer